# SSH: I have a public key in authorized_keys on two hosts, but no private key. Why am I able to login with no password?

Tags: ssh

I have two hosts (A and B) with the same public key stored in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Why am I able to ssh between them without a password. The keypair was generated on a third host (C), so I am confident the private key is not available on either A or B.

**Update**: Answered my own question, and prompting from heavyd was helpful. Turns out I had 'OpenSSH Agent Forwarding' turned on on my local SSH client. The local SSH client (machine C) does have access to the private key, and was acting as agent to authenticate machine A to machine B. This is not what I want, and I'm turning off Agent Forwarding in my client.

tl;dr: Agent Forwarding

Comment: Does commenting out the key (put a `#` at the beginning of the line) change anything?

Comment: If I comment out the key (on both hosts' authorized_keys), I am forced to use a password.

Comment: But the three hosts don't share the same home-directory, and hence ~/.ssh, do they?

Comment: Running `ssh -vv user@host` should tell you which key is getting used.

Comment: @mpy: A and B do share home-directory (NFS)

Comment: @heavyd: 
`debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Offering agent key: "user@C"

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen *** lastkey **** hint -1

debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp **:**:**:**.....

debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)`

Comment: @heavyd The fp being used matches the fp of the public key (as reported by ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/authorized_keys)

Comment: Tried, have to wait 8 hours as a newbie to this stack exchange.

Comment: It sounds like your private key is stored without encryption. You might want to look into that too, as it is not secure.

Comment: @vy32: Private key is encrypted. Agent forwarding uses a local agent on my machine to store the private key after I've decrypted it to login to server1. With forwarding enabled, when the SSH session on server1 is used to launch another SSH to session2, the SSH client on server1 forwards the challenge from session2 back to my machine, where the SSH agent responds, through server1, to server2's challenge. It means I don't need to decrypt my key when ssh'ing from server1 to server2, but it was scary when it first happened. http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#fwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question, and prompting from heavyd was helpful. Turns out I had Agent Forwarding turned on on my local SSH client. The local SSH client (machine C) does have access to the private key, and was acting as agent to authenticate machine A to machine B. This is not what I want, and I'm turning off Agent Forwarding in my client.